# heatmap hashtag and location in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I have Pandas Dataframe as below

[newdf[['name_left','text']]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9yx.png)

from each text column I would like to extract every hashtag and create heatmap
with name_left on X axis and extracted hashtag on Y axis

I can perform count of each hashtag using code below

newdf.text.str.extractall(r'(#\w+)').reset_index(level=0).drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()

unfortunately im struggling to add name_left and later create heatmap to see correlations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_left': ['Canada', 'Peru'],
                   'text': ['asdf #broccoli sadfsd #milk', 'sdfsd #king bbas #toast']})

df = df.groupby(['name_left']).apply(lambda x: x.text.str.extractall(r'(#\w+)').reset_index(level=0).drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts())

print(df)
```

```
Canada     #milk        1
           #broccoli    1
Peru       #king        1
           #toast       1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks  but it will not count if hashtag more then once in country

Comment: i dont quite get what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Comment: i get confused as it didnt work on my dataset but worked well on your example luckly i notice later i have to reset index (.reset_index(drop=True)) and all worked fine thanks for advice!!!